# Save and Load UISwitch state in TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

I want to save the switch state. I created custom cell class witch print one Switch on label but there is problem that if i search some text then Table View reload and my selected switch State is going to change, Is it possible to Maintain that state ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  ....
selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
CfResultFatch *temp = [result objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",temp.complanName);
//[cell.switchOnOff setOn:NO];
[cell.switchOnOff setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.switchOnOff addTarget:self action:@selector(selectUser:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell.switchOnOff setTag:indexPath.row];
cell.lblUserName.text = temp.complanName;
cell.textFld.text = temp.cipd;
return cell;
}
```

//selectUser which is call when switch state change

```
-(IBAction)selectUser:(UISwitch*)sender{
if(sender.on)
{
    [selectedpet addObject:[result objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
}else{
    NSLog(@"%@",sender);
    for(int j=0;j<[selectedpet count]; j++)
                   {
                       CfResultFatch *temp = [result objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
                       CfResultFatch *temp1= [selectedpet objectAtIndex:j];
                       if([(temp.complanName)isEqualToString:(temp1.complanName)]) {
                      [selectedpet removeObjectAtIndex:j];
          }
    }
  }
}
```

//and Search in searchBar this methode is call when search some text and the data is change from data base problem is here is i select 0 and 1 index switch on and then search some text, the new data in table view come with 0 and 1 index ON,how to maintain it and how to get my previous state of Switch

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
 NSString *weburl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://192.168.1.196/ravi/searchUser.php?mname=",searchText];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:weburl];
 NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 [self getData:data];
 [temptab reloadData];
}
```

And ya. sorry for my poor english

Comment: Just a note: There is no reason to set the tag of `cell.switchOnOff` twice. Also, the target of `cell.switchOnOff` could be set when initializing the cells. There is no reason to do this every time a cell is reused. Furthermore, you might benefit from subclassing your `UITableViewCell` and then set up the cell in Interface Builder (e.g. add a switch), set the class of the cell to your subclass and then you don't have to struggle with tags and setting up your `UISwitch` programmatically. In the long run, I believe this gives a better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the state of the `UISwitch` when it is changed. It might not be the best way to do this, but you could store the states in a dictionary like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *states = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[states setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.on] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]]
```

Then, when showing the `UITableViewCell`:

```
if ([states objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]] != nil)
    cell.switchOnOff.on = [[states objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]] boolValue]
else
    cell.switchOnOff.on = NO;
```

Comment: You will put `states` in your interface. Then you will allocate `states` before using it. This could be in your `viewDidLoad:`. Then, the last part of my answer you will put in your `tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you reuse your cells.